# CLI menu for programming assignments, dividing code into chunks

Tags: c, menu, command-line-interface

I'm a student and I have assignments in C. No, I'm not asking you to make my assignments)) I'm looking for a way to improve their output and presentation.

Assignments are given as source on problems are in the comments, there is up to 10 problems in one assignment.

Here is an example of formatting:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    {
        //Problem 1. a) Do something
        int X = 123;
        // b) And now do it from the different angle
        int Y = 0;
        int* pY = &Y;
        *pY = 123;
    }

    {
        //Problem 2. a) Do something
        int X = 123;
        // b) And now do it from the different angle
        int Y = 0;
        int* pY = &Y;
        *pY = 123;
    }

    {
        //Problem 3. a) Do something
        int X = 123;
        // b) And now do it from the different angle
        int Y = 0;
        int* pY = &Y;
        *pY = 123;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We use `{}` separate problems so that you can use same names for different problems. Problems need to be defended and explained to our teacher.

When I'm showing this to the teacher I have to comment all problems except one I'm showing, show it, comment it, uncomment next and so on. That takes a lot of time. Problems are not absolutely simple, they are usually involve few functions loops and some times structs.

The question is how to separate each problem so that everything inside it works properly.

Should I make a switch nested in while which will call functions containing exercises?
Or are their better solutions?

P.S. I'm not asking for the recipe, I just need an advice.

Answer (score 0):

you can develop menu driven program:

```
char ch='y';
int op=0;
while(ch=='y'){
  printf("1. problem 1\n");
  printf("2. problem 2\n");
  printf("choose your option from above:");
  scanf("%d",&op);
  switch(op){
    case 1:{
      //code for problem 1
      break;
    }
    case 2:{
      //code for problem 2
      break;
    }
    default:{
      //invalid option
  }
}
printf("Do you want to continue(y/n):");
scanf("%c",ch);
}
```